# How to insert a nonstandard language input area in my website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, textarea

Hi I want insert a nonstandard language input area in my web site. It work like gmail chat box language transilation. how can I create that kind of an input area in my website.

I want to transilate English to TAMIL language. The form contains some other input areas. I want to transilate the description input area only.

Comment: Please define non-standard language.

Comment: Why not just put a link to Google Translate that will translate your webpage?  You can have a flag for each country that is a link of their language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [Google Virtual Keyboard](http://code.google.com/apis/language/virtualkeyboard/overview.html)? I doubt you actually want to input non-standard languages, which would imply that you want to input characters outside of Unicode.